# cakePHP redirection with $this->referer() not working properly

Tags: php, cakephp

I have one view file of TestController And on that I have added comment form (the url of page on which my page exist is www.example.com/test/view/slug)now comment form is posting on url www.example.com/comments/add action comment is adding successfully  after addition I have written (in comment/add method)

```
            $this->redirect($this->referer());
```

what I was expecting is it should redirect to www.example.com/test/view/slug . its redirecting on that url on my localhost but when I deployed my application it is redirecting not redirecting propery it is redirecting on url www.example.com/comment/www.example.com  and giving error

```
Error: The requested address '/comments/www.example.com' was not found on this server.
```

Comment: check your routes.php there may be some problem .

Comment: I have written only one route in route.php which is used for home page redirection  Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'home', 'home'));  @Abhishek:is there is any problem then it should not work on my local as well.

Comment: yes you are right, But there may be possibilities check your .htaccess files on local system as well as on your live server, Have you checked that a what value $this->referer() is giving it.

Comment: on both htaccess we have written only one rule RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]  .

Comment: and url-rewriting tags in .htaccess are where as rewrite engine On ? and what is the value of this  $this->referer() ?

Comment: value of $this->referer() is http://www.example.com/test/view/first_chapter  .and yes my mod rewrite is on.

Comment: so now you check your function view() there may be going wrong as your are getting a right refererr ? and also try by just using this hardcoded value , check to see it runs or not ? like  $this->redirect('example.com/test/view/first_chapter') ;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46519/discussion-between-ganesh-patil-and-abhishek)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

`$this->redirect( Router::url( $this->referer(), true ) );`

This will use FULL urls in your redirect and this may fix your problem with adding your redirect to the current URL instead of just using it.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this

```
$this->redirect($this->referer());
```