# $this->request->referer() not working properly (Cakephp 2)

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect

There may be a lot of question regarding this but no help from these all . . I have the same issue as [On this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479023/cakephp-redirection-with-this-referer-not-working-properly).

I am requesting from url http://example.com/projects/phase/test_phase2#5591409f-ce8c-4a8a-a92d-77360a11ef94 to save the progress and this is requesting on the url http://example.com/phases/update_progress . now i want to redirect my page on back to the url . I am using these all . But no luck .

```
$this->redirect($this->referer('/'));
$this->redirect($this->referer());
$this->redirect($this->request->referer());
$this->redirect( Router::url( $this->referer(), true ) );
```

after this it is redirecting to http://example.com/phases/example.com But i want it to be redirect on http://example.com/projects/phase/test_phase2#5591409f-ce8c-4a8a-a92d-77360a11ef94.

routes.php is

```
Router::parseExtensions('json');
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));
Router::connect('/login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/admin/login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => true));
Router::connect('/contents/*', array('controller' => 'contents', 'action' => 'view'));
```

.htaccess is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

it is working very well on localhost . All files are same on both server.

Is there any other method to do this ??

Comment: `$this->redirect( $this->referer() );`

Comment: tried it allready . But no luck

Comment: `http://example.com/phases/example.com` - really? `projects` is missing, it's not `phase` anymore but `phases`, and the domain is being appended to the URL? Are you sure that you haven't made a mistake here in your example data?

Comment: yes this is  not phase anymore but phases. no mistake . this is working perfectly on my local system . you are right the domain name is appending with this url . Can't understand where i am wron g

Comment: and this is because I am sending request from (controller=>projects,action="phase") to (controller=>phases,action=>"update_progress")

Comment: What exactly does `$this->referer()` and `$this->request->referer()` return, and does it match `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`? On a side note, the `redirect()` method internally transforms the given URL to a full URL. ps, please use @username tags in your comments, otherwise the one you are talking too might not get notified.

Comment: `i want it to be redirect on http://...#5591409f-ce8c-4a8a-a92d-77360a11ef94` The url fragment is never going to be in the referer - as it's not passed to the server at all. Your routes have no bearing on what the referer is.

Comment: does $this->referer() or $this->request->referer() even return anything ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because `it is redirecting to http://example.com/phases/example.com` indicates a problem/bug but the code in the question doesn't reproduce it. This question can't be answered without some input from the OP, and no input is forthcoming.

Comment: @AD7six I agree. There might be something in his app controller that creates this behavior. Or some plugin or component might be responsible. My advice to him would be to remove all plugins and components that are not essential to this functionality and also removes all unrelated code from the app controller or any beforeFilter callback in the controller until he can spot the situation where this behavior occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this issue by creating a [HistoryComponent](https://github.com/otoso/Cake-History-Component) that saves the requests in the user's session (including the get parameters). The obvious disadvantage of this approach is that it relies on sessions. Since the session is the same in all tabs the back buttons might influence each other in a multi-tab environment.

If you want to use it:

- Add the plugin in bootstrap.php
- Use the previous_page variable in your view (pass it to the back button)